# Will console.log affect to async performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, asynchronous, console.log

I know it's might be silly. But at least, I got this feeling many times.

Sometimes I'm trying to fix some bugs, mostly with Angular's `$http` request, callbacks or even with Node `promise`.

When things go wrong, I try to put some `console.log` to detect the code flow, and from that moment, (mostly) the bugs will disappear! It's not only happened to me.

So I think, somehow, `console.log` affect to the performance (make the program run a bit slower), and then, it makes the bugs gone!

[image]

I know I'm not the only one think this. Do you think it's possible? Or have you also meet this kind of issue before? please discuss!

Comment: I think just having Developer Tools open can slow things down.

Comment: But it also happen to me in node.js apps

Comment: `It's not only happened to me` ... `I know I'm not the only one think this` ... what did the others do?

Answer (score 5):

Certainly!

This is especially noticeable when logging many items in a loop, or when logging complex objects. Calls to `console.log` can be time consuming, and consequently, that delay can resolve some of your race conditions.

Comment: yeah! thanks for pointing out, I got the feeling but not sure what to describe it, race condition is a good word to describe my problem!

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript usually considered as single threaded.
that why it is most likely any extra code row will effect the performance.

here is a great answer why it is not sure that it is :(

[Is javascript guaranteed to be single-threaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734025/is-javascript-guaranteed-to-be-single-threaded)

Good Luck!

Comment: ah, yes, I forgot about that, it's single threaded so it might be slow for sure when we do logging. thank you so much!